# (Dynamic Memory Allocation) why maximize peak utilization?

Tags: c, malloc, heap-memory, dynamic-memory-allocation, virtual-memory

I was reading a textbook which says that:
[image]

I'm totally lost, let's says:

**n = 10** and ***p* (required payload) = 800** bytes,

Does it mean that on the **n = 9** which is 9th allocate request, P<sub>9</sub> needs to be 792 bytes( suppose a single minimum allocate is 8 bytes)? Is my understanding correct?

Comment: What do you mean by `p`?

Comment: @melpomene It's in the quoted text: **If an application requests a block of *p* bytes, ...**

Comment: Yes, "If". Are you saying you have an application that requests 800 bytes? If so, in which request R_i does this happen?

Comment: Note that the sentence you're referring to is the definition of the term *payload*. `p` is effectively a local variable within that definition.

Comment: @melpomene the 9th request has 792 bytes, the 10th request allocate the final 8 bytes

Comment: To answer what P_9 is, you need to know what the requests R_0 .. R_9 are (that is, for each request you need to know whether it is an allocate request or a free request and its payload size).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understand the text, that allocator objective is to maximize *Pi* (sum of allocated memory at instant *i*). The peak utilization up to *k* is the ratio of the max of what could be allocated divided by the heap size at *k*.

Since there is a number of *alloc* and *free* at  *i*, if the allocator is too basic and does not handle well the requests, it might be unable to answer another allocation request (for instance due to heap fragmentation, see exemple below).

A smart allocator might allow a maximal payload, at the expense of a slower response.

On the opposite you might have a fast allocator that might not be able to maximize the aggregate payload *Pk* after a number of requests.

To give a (simple) exemple, having that chain of requests

```
R1: alloc(1000)
R2: alloc(2000)
R3: alloc(1500)
R4: free(R1)
R5: free(R2)
R6: alloc(3000) => use space from R1+R2?
```

At R6 a basic allocator might not be able to understand it could reuse the space freed from R1 and R2, giving a low *peak* ratio, and the heap size is unnecessary higher than it should.

A smarter one might do, but at the likely expense of more CPU /resources.

Answer (score 0):

The assumption behind this is that memory is a precious commodity, and we should try to avoid wasting it. If peak utilization is low, it means there's lots of memory reserved for the heap that isn't being used.

Peak utilization doesn't refer to any specific allocation. P<sub>i</sub> is the total payloads from `i` successive requests. So it doesn't make sense to refer to a single `p = 800 bytes` in this analysis. max<sub>i≤k</sub>P<sub>i</sub> is the peak of a graph of P<sub>i</sub> from request `0` to `k`. Each allocation adds to the heap utilization, although frees will reduce it.

You need enough heap memory to satisfy the maximum amount of memory you'll ever allocate at simultaneously, but if you have much more then the rest is being wasted. Maximizing peak utilization means to try to find this sweet spot.

Comment: but let say p = 800 bytes, how to maximize peak utilization?

Comment: If you're only doing a single allocation, then you should have a heap with only 800 bytes.